# How to provide output Parameter SqlProcedure in powerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Hi I have Procedure with following definition

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[import_copy_table_to_backup]
    @source_tablename nvarchar(max),
    @target_tablename nvarchar(max),
    @source_filename nvarchar(max),
    @rows   bigint OUTPUT
    
AS Begin
```

And I am getting following exception
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Procedure or function 'import_copy_table_to_backup' expects parameter
'@rows', which was not supplied."
At E:\PowerShell-Scripts\fetchDataFiles.ps1:233 char:3

Below is my code

```
$SqlQuery = "exec import_copy_table_to_backup '$tableName', 'import_abcd_data', '$fileFullName' "
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
        $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
        
        $outParameter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
        $outParameter.ParameterName = "@rows"
        $outParameter.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
        $outParameter.DbType = [System.Data.DbType]::Int64
        
        $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add($outParameter) | Out-Null
        
        $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
        $SqlConnection.Close()
```

I am new to both Powershell & Sql Procedures. Ask here is to know the correct way to supply the output Parameter.

Thanks Much!

Comment: Have you tried including `, @rows output` in your  `$SqlQuery` definition? Also, this code is open to SQL Injection, see obligatory [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) reference.

Comment: Thanks much @AlwaysLearning, it works with adding it as a part of $sqlQuery definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use SqlDataAdapter here (or almost ever).  Just use SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, and then read the output parameter value.  Also use parameters for the other stored procedure arguments.  eg

```
$SqlQuery = "exec import_copy_table_to_backup @tableName, 'import_abcd_data', @fileFullName, @rows out "
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$tableNameParameter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
$tableNameParameter.ParameterName = "@tableName"
$tableNameParameter.DbType = [System.Data.DbType]::String

$fileFullNameParameter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
$fileFullNameParameter.ParameterName = "@fileFullName"
$fileFullNameParameter.DbType = [System.Data.DbType]::String
        
$outParameter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
$outParameter.ParameterName = "@rows"
$outParameter.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
$outParameter.DbType = [System.Data.DbType]::Int64
        
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add($tableNameParameter) | Out-Null
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add($fileFullNameParameter) | Out-Null
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add($outParameter) | Out-Null

$fileFullNameParameter.Value = $fileFullName
$tableNameParameter.Value = $tableName
        
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$rows = [Int64]$outParameter.Value

$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: With David your approach I get an error The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type, not String Objects, is that for the second parameter as hard coded string or something else?

Comment: Don't know why, but I still get an exception with above code that an active connection is required for ExecuteNonQuery and I think $SqlConnection in $SqlCmd is still active. Do you see a reason why it won't work? Thanks

Comment: So I added following line before executing the query - $SqlCmd.Connection.Open(); and it works, could you please confirm if that is expected? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is expected.